# Macro variable, %eval and character operand in sas

Tags: sas, eval, sas-macro

I have a problem with sas macro and macro variable. When I use it, I get information: 'A character operand was found in the %eval  function or %if condition were numeric.

I have something like distribution (d1-d5) and I want to get similar variables but shifted about diff (data before diff are equal 0). Below example table - of course I need to do something for much bigger table.

```
Example_table
Name d1    d2   d3   d4  d5  diff 
A   0.2  0.2  0.1   0.2  0.3  1
B   0.3  0.1  0.4   0.3  0    2
C   0.1  0.2   0    0.4  0.3  2

Table I want to get: (new_table)
Name n1  n2   n3   n4    n5   diff
A    0   0.2  0.2  0.1   0.2   1
B    0   0    0.3  0.1   0.4   2
C    0   0    0.1  0.2   0     2




Data example_table;
Name = A B C;
d1 = 0.2 0.3 0.1;
d2 = 0.2 0.1 0.2;
d3 = 0.1 0.4 0;
d4 = 0.2 0.3 0.4;
d5 = 0.3 0 0.3;
diff = 1 2 2;
run;

%macro distr ();
%local  i;
%do i = 1 %to 5;
 if &i. <= diff then n&i. = 0;
 else n&i. = d%eval(&i. - diff);
/* I cant compute this eval, it looks like diff is character variable..., but it doesn't */
%end;
%mend;

Data new_table;
Set example_table;
%distr();
run;
```

Comment: One note - please see how Tom created your example dataset, and future questions should have that in it.

Answer (score 1):

The macro processor knows nothing about the values of your dataset variables.

You are trying to subtract the letters `diff` from the value of the macro variable `i`.  That cannot work.

You will want to use SAS code to do your data manipulation, not macro code. For example by using arrays.

```
data example_table;
  input Name d1-d5 diff ;
cards;
A   0.2  0.2  0.1   0.2  0.3  1
B   0.3  0.1  0.4   0.3  0    2
C   0.1  0.2   0    0.4  0.3  2
;

data want;
  set example_table;
  array d d1-d5;
  array n n1-n5;
  do index=1 to dim(n);
    if 1 <= index-diff <= dim(d) then n[index]=d[index-diff];
    else n[index]=0;
  end;
  drop index d1-d5;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    Name    diff    n1     n2     n3     n4     n5

 1       A       1      0    0.2    0.2    0.1    0.2
 2       B       2      0    0.0    0.3    0.1    0.4
 3       C       2      0    0.0    0.1    0.2    0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up SAS and Macro language here, specifically:

```
 %eval(&i. - diff)
```

`%eval` is a macro function, meaning it applies to the *text of the code*.  `diff` is a SAS data step variable, meaning it has some value - but `%eval` only operates on the text *itself*.  So `%eval` is trying to take `&i` (a number) and subtract from it the letters `diff` (not a number).

Fortunately it's pretty easy - `&i` is available to the SAS datastep, as a number.  You can use an array to resolve the problem!  First declare the array, then...

```
else n&i. = d[&i].;
```

Of course, you don't need to use the macro language at all here.

```
data new_table;
  set example_table;
  array d[5] d1-d5;  *technically d1-d5 is unneeded here as those are the default names;
  array n[5] n1-n5;  *also n1-n5 unneeded, but it is more clear;
  do i = 1 to dim(d);
    if i <= diff then n[i] = 0;
    else n[i] = d[i];
  end;
run;
```